# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>?' - flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving the following error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List?' while converting the map to BarModel object

despite receiving the list of int from response, it is throwing type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List? when assigning it to the openDays

```
List<int>? openDays;

BarModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    print(json['open_days']); // [1, 2, 3]
    barId = json['bar_id'];
    barName = json['bar_name'];
    barAddress = json['bar_address'];
    openDays = json['open_days']; // error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>?'
  }
```

Comment: Maybe the returning json response is String.
Could you please provide the whole json response to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Map` you are inputting is the actual result of a `jsonDecode` of a JSON string it must mean that the JSON was actually formatted like

```
{
  "open_days" : "[1, 2, 3]"
  ...
}
```

instead of this

```
{
  "open_days" : [1, 2, 3]
  ...
}
```

which is the correct way if you want it to be an actual list and not a string.

If you have no control over the JSON string you could solve it by `jsonDecode` that part another time, so like

```
openDays = jsonDecode(json['open_days']);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! so that's why I'm facing this issue

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was scratching my head over this

Comment: jsonDecode(json['open_days']) but that was done already, because map is result of jsonDecode(response.body)

Comment: @shaktigoyal I'm aware of that, but the string "[1, 2, 3]" is actually valid JSON again, so you could fix it like that to turn it into a list

Comment: Just tested it! It worked!

Comment: You saved the backend developer from extra work! haha! Else I would have to instruct him to fix the json format from backend